# How to add option in display mode of display setting in category in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, category, admin-panel

There are three options (1. products only, 2. Static block only, 3. Static block and products) in display mode, i want add two more options so can any one help me  to add more options.

[image]

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Create a plugin following way:

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode">
        <plugin name="WebkulCart" type="Md\Nspc\Plugin\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Mode.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Category\Attribute\Source;

class Mode
{
    public function afterGetAllOptions(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $result[] = ['value' => 'CUSTOM_MODE', 'label' => 'Custom Mode'];
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

Comment: thnks for reply, all command are not working when i put your code in di.cml file, so i have change it to "<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode" type="md\nspc\Plugin\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode" />" after this commands are working but at admin panel it gives 500 internal server error

Comment: Why you use preference, Use plugin and "md\nspc" should be uppercase first.

Comment: It's tested code. I use 'SR\StackExchange' instead of 'Vendor\Module'

Comment: This one is working for me:

<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode">
        <plugin name="WebkulCart" type="Md\Nspc\Plugin\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

Comment: Thats nice format.